# How to enable Root Login when installing Ubuntu 16.04.3

Tags: system-installation, permissions, login

all. I couldn't set root Login when installing ubuntu-server-16.04.3; does  anyone know how to setup that? (enable when install  system, not after that.)

Answer (score 0):

I've get one, install and use preseed file, config like  this could work, any else?

```
d-i passwd/root-login boolean true
d-i passwd/root-password password root
```

Comment: And where do you put that file ?

Comment: PXE install,  follow this: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/PXE-netboot-install